# Adding Firebase to a Wear OS and mobile app?

Tags: android, firebase, wear-os

I have a Android Wear OS app which also have a mobile companion app. I've just added Firebase to the Wear app and it works well. Now I would like to add Firebase to the mobile app as well.

As Android Wear and mobile apps have the same package name how can I differ between the 2 when for example sending FCM notifications or for Firebase analytics?

If I send a FCM to the user segment using package name will the notification be sent to both the mobile device and the wear device? And would that be cause multiple notifications on the mobile device because of the notification bridging?

Comment: There are a number of ways that you could approach this - including the device-specific registration token, creating a device-specific user property, or subscribing to different topics - but you don't really give enough detail about your use case to recommend one. What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, For the mobile app I mainly intend to use it for analytics and FCM notifications.

For analytics I guess (as you say) the differentiation could be solved by adding a user property.

Comment: For FCM notifications I mainly intended to use it to engage people who have my app installed but have not used it for a while. For that I planned to use the feature in the FCM console to send a notification to a certain package name. 

But since the wear and mobile app have the same name I'm wondering how that would work.. Subscribing to different topics would only work if the user opens the app after upgrading but I would also like to reach people who have not opened the (mobile) app in a while.